# Drupal GraphQL integration issues

Tags: api, drupal, graphql, headless, gatsby

BACKGROUND
I have a backend of a typical Drupal 8 install, exporting into an api via the JSON-API module. I'm using Gatsby as the front-end, which has a built in Drupal-GraphQL source-plugin. (I am also new to GraphQL, so this may simply be a rookie error.) Querying in simple ways via GraphiQL works fine, however...

THE PROBLEM
GraphQL doesn't seem to recognize the Drupal schema, meaning arguments cannot be passed to types/nodes (see screenshot). I am not exactly sure how to phrase the problem, since I can only see that it's not working for whatever reason. This project is for a client on a tight deadline, so any help at all very much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This isn't intended to be an answer per say. Just too complex to add as a comment.

I've been working with the wordpress plugin and inspecting the examples from that I find a slightly different structure for pulling an individual post:

```
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query currentPostQuery($id: String!) {
    wordpressPost(id: { eq: $id }) {
      title
      content
    }
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        title
        subtitle
      }
    }
  }
`
```

And though I'm sure the drupal plugin will have a different structure, is it possible graphql is confused because you pass:

```
node(id: "xxxx")
```

versus

```
node(id: {eq: "xxxx"})
```

and it looks like you're querying all nodes instead of running a single query. Or rather, it doesn't appear correct to try to pass an ID on the node channel there, expecting it to return if it matches that ID.

I haven't had to mess with drupal and gatsby yet, so I'm no official source. Just saying the query itself looks odd to me. Do you have a link to documentation that shows this is how you query a single node in gatsby with the drupal source plugin?